# Zen Bound 2 render issue

Tags: technical-issues, android, zen-bound-2

Anyone else have issues with the models not rendering for [zen bound](http://zenbound.com/) 2 on recent versions of android lollipop?
 `(Version 5.1.1)`

Any one know of a fix? Rope and pins appear, wooden models are translucent.

Edit: The game appears to be gone from google play, maybe they dropped support.

Update : [Asked](http://steamcommunity.com/app/61600/discussions/0/451848854984588272/) on steam discussion board 
Still trying to find the best way to contact [secret exit](http://secretexit.com/).

Comment: Anyone? This was such a great app for waiting rooms and long lines.

Comment: Reading from [its Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/ZenBound), the app is supposed to be still in [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.secretexit.zb2) (it's country-locked, I can't open it from here). However, for support issue, I guess you have done what we can, and probably need to wait until their reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point there does not appear to be a solution.